# Gitlab project : 500 Whoops, something went wrong on our end

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

Hi every one i migrated gitlab-ce into a new instance with new domain name

**Migration :**

- Gitlab Backup --> Restore

**Gitlab Version:**

- 13.6.2

**Problem :**

when Clicking a Project it returns :

`"500  Whoops, something went wrong on our end "`

**Gitlab status**

```
run: alertmanager: (pid 1766) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1764) 3439s
run: crond: (pid 1775) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1770) 3439s
run: gitaly: (pid 1724) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1723) 3439s
run: gitlab-exporter: (pid 1750) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1749) 3439s
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 1761) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1748) 3439s
run: grafana: (pid 1767) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1765) 3439s
run: logrotate: (pid 1752) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1751) 3439s
run: nginx: (pid 1746) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1745) 3439s
run: node-exporter: (pid 1742) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1740) 3439s
run: postgres-exporter: (pid 1769) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1768) 3439s
run: postgresql: (pid 1726) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1720) 3439s
run: prometheus: (pid 1774) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1773) 3439s
run: puma: (pid 1747) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1734) 3439s
run: redis: (pid 1718) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1716) 3439s
run: redis-exporter: (pid 1757) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1756) 3439s
run: registry: (pid 1760) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1759) 3439s
run: sidekiq: (pid 1741) 3439s; run: log: (pid 1731) 3439s
```

**Application Check**

```
Checking GitLab subtasks ...

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell: ... GitLab Shell version >= 13.13.0 ? ... OK (13.13.0)
Running /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Internal API available: OK
Redis available via internal API: OK
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Gitaly ...

Gitaly: ... default ... OK

Checking Gitaly ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Sidekiq: ... Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking Incoming Email ...

Incoming Email: ... Reply by email is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking Incoming Email ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP: ... Server: ldapmain
Exception: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab App ...

Git configured correctly? ... yes
Database config exists? ... yes
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config up to date? ... yes
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Uploads directory exists? ... yes
Uploads directory has correct permissions? ... yes
Uploads directory tmp has correct permissions? ... skipped (no tmp uploads folder yet)
Init script exists? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
Init script up-to-date? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
Projects have namespace: ...
Mahdi Hannoun / test ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-application / frontend ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-application / backend ... yes
Julien Hay / ProxyBench ... yes
flowbird-bi / data-management ... yes
flowbird-bi / reports-management ... yes
smart-data / abbakan ... yes
Hamid Zemirline / deployment-automation ... yes
rbc / ged-ratios ... yes
Oumar Fall / bytel ... yes
bouygues_dataviz / frontend ... yes
bouygues_dataviz / backend ... yes
E-TIPI / etipi-react-native-application ... yes
Julien Hay / VilleFR ... yes
flowbird-bi / report-sources ... yes
flowbird-bi / report-queries ... yes
octopeek-io / front-end ... yes
octopeek-io / old-back-end ... yes
showroomprive / archive / frontend-lot1 ... yes
Laure Normand / FormationDB ... yes
librestamp / librestamp ... yes
flowbird-bi / deployment-automation ... yes
showroomprive / archive / parse-prepare-process ... yes
showroomprive / scraping-vente-privee ... yes
octopeek-io / site ... yes
Julien Hay / TwitterCrawler ... yes
showroomprive / front-end ... yes
Sedki Boubakri / srp ... yes
showroomprive / back-end ... yes
showroomprive / extract-image-srp ... yes
showroomprive / archive / application-libs-broken ... yes
Guillaume Ambrois / my-test-project ... yes
flowbird-bi / data-processing ... yes
Hamid Zemirline / src_flb_bi ... yes
Julien Hay / thang-matching ... yes
Pierre Gauthier / scraping_linkedin ... yes
smaps / back-end ... yes
flowbird-uk / poc ... yes
matching-rh / archive / front-end ... yes
matching-rh / archive / back-end ... yes
matching-rh / archive / application-libs ... yes
showroomprive / functional-tests ... yes
Guillaume Ambrois / application-libs ... yes
E-TIPI / application-libs ... yes
showroomprive / data-ingestion ... yes
Guillaume Ambrois / back-end ... yes
librestamp / application-libs ... yes
Guillaume Ambrois / application-libs-DO_NOT_TOUCH ... yes
showroomprive / application-libs ... yes
Pierre Gauthier / Matching_linkedin_page_jaune ... yes
matching-rh / archive / front-end-demo ... yes
infra / ansible-hortonworks ... yes
misc / requests ... yes
Krystian Luczyszyn / scrapping ... yes
Pierre Gauthier / MAJ_Index_Linkedin ... yes
Guillaume Ambrois / private ... yes
test-gitlab / test ... yes
Djamal KESSOUM / Infra_freeipa-ansible ... yes
Guillaume Ambrois / front-end ... yes
showroomprive / scraping-privalia ... yes
side-effects-detection / application_libs ... yes
side-effects-detection / backend ... yes
side-effects-detection / frontend ... yes
octopeek-io / old-front-end ... yes
Besma Khalfi / data-ingestion ... yes
showroomprive / scheduled-scripts ... yes
Moncef Mouffok / emailing ... yes
infra / octopeek-dev-sandbox ... yes
infra / devices-conf ... yes
corp-agency / data-acquisition ... yes
Guillaume Ambrois / gsuite-to-sheets ... yes
infra / ansible-octopeek-infra ... yes
corp-agency / data-normalization ... yes
infra / tools ... yes
showroomprive / data-restitution ... yes
Julien Hay / LinkedInCrawler ... yes
Oumar Fall / octopeek-commons ... yes
corp-agency / misc-scripts ... yes
octopeek-commons / front-octopeek-menu ... yes
octopeek-commons / front-octopeek-multi-language ... yes
octopeek-commons / front-file-drop-upload ... yes
octopeek-templates / octopeek-workspace ... yes
octopeek-io / deep-end ... yes
Oumar Fall / node-backend ... yes
corp-agency / data-processing ... yes
octopeek-io / back-end ... yes
Bertrand Laporte / cicd-test ... yes
Besma Khalfi / BesmaProject ... yes
Besma Khalfi / CI-CD testing  ... yes
these_mmouffok / memoire ... yes
data-acquisition / sirene ... yes
data-acquisition / pages-jaunes ... yes
Mahdi MENACER / workshop-git ... yes
matching-rh / archive / deep-end ... yes
these_mmouffok / deep_domain_adaptation_code ... yes
data-acquisition-tools / email-creation ... yes
RH-Matching-demo / front-end ... yes
these_mmouffok / sketch_based_3D_shape_code ... yes
RH-Matching-demo / back-end ... yes
RH-Matching-demo / Deep-end-demo ... yes
data-ingestion / company ... yes
academai / jupyter ... yes
matching-rh / deep-end-emploi-collectivites ... yes
Carole Lambert / deep-end-emploi-collectivites ... yes
Julien Hay / Twirona ... yes
matching-rh / back-end-demo-emploi-collectivites ... yes
matching-rh / front-end-demo-emploi-collectivites ... yes
RH-Matching-demo / front-end-demo-emploi-collectivites ... yes
octopeek-io / catalogue-services ... yes
data-performance / AVY-Salon Aveyron ... yes
octopeek-io / Mongodb_catalogue ... yes
octopeek-io / catalogue-services-front-admin ... yes
octopeek-io / api_catalogue_services ... yes
Oumar Fall / demo-cicd ... yes
octopeek-web / apache-configuration ... yes
infra / octopeek-template ... yes
infra / octopeek-provisioning ... yes
Oumar Fall / api_ioss ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-infra-deploy / ambari-deploy ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-infra-deploy / kubespray ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-infra-deploy / helm-charts ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-infra-deploy / k8s-storage ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-app-deploy / frontend-helm ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-app-deploy / backend-helm ... yes
Samy Tafasca / AutoEDA ... yes
Oumar Fall / demo-ansible-gitlab-ci ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-infra-deploy / ci-experiment ... yes
Hamid Zemirline / aaa-service ... yes
IOSS / ioss-ui-socle ... yes
IOSS / ioss-user-mgt-service ... yes
IOSS / ioss-authentication ... yes
Erwan Benkara / AutoEDA ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-application / component-deploy-backend ... yes
octopeek-xenonstack / bdaas-app-deploy / component-deploy-backend-helm ... yes
Hamid Zemirline / helm-repo ... yes
IOSS / ioss-user-mgt-api ... yes
IOSS / ioss-deploy ... yes
IOSS / ioss-user-log-service ... yes
IOSS / ioss-dev-stack ... yes
IOSS / helm-charts ... yes
SedkiBoubakri / EdaPerformanceTest ... yes
weather-data-acquisition / Web scraping ... yes
SedkiBoubakri / Profiling ... yes
IOSS / cdap-tests ... yes
Thomas Levy / explainability ... yes
IOSS / cdap-operator ... yes
IOSS / cdap-build ... yes
IOSS / cdap ... yes
IOSS / cdap-plugins ... yes
CDAP-plugins / product-auto-extract ... yes
CDAP-plugins / elasticsearch-source-plugin ... yes
CDAP-plugins / diffbotcrawl-action ... yes
CDAP-plugins / octopeek-http-plugins ... yes
CDAP-plugins / explainability-poc ... yes
IOSS / pipelines ... yes
CDAP-plugins / webdataextractor ... yes
Julien Hay / POCImmo ... yes
Samy Tafasca / autoeda_spark ... yes
Stephane Durfort / Python Plugins POC ... yes
CDAP-plugins / python-plugins ... yes
IOSS / cdap-plugin-test ... yes
CDAP-plugins / interpreted-Python-for-matching ... yes
IOSS / hub-templates ... yes
misc / ohb-cluster-archives ... yes
CDAP-plugins / diffbot-tools ... yes
IOSS / devops-scripts ... yes
IOSS / mvn-depgraph ... yes
CDAP-plugins / product-classification ... yes
Ahmed Zouari / Product_Classification ... yes
CDAP-plugins / scraping-confidence ... yes
CDAP-plugins / text-normalization-directive ... yes
CDAP-plugins / random-hash ... yes
IOSS / cdap_cookbook ... yes
CDAP-plugins / text-normalization-directive_with_parameter ... yes
CDAP-plugins / sentiment-analysis ... yes
CDAP-plugins / oit-commons ... yes
IOSS / french-product-classification ... yes
CDAP-plugins / TextNormalizationPlugin ... yes
CDAP-plugins / ai-enrich-plugin ... yes
CDAP-plugins / aienrich ... yes
IOSS / automapping ... yes
Stephane Durfort / Mvn Build Number Test ... yes
CDAP-plugins / widgets-demo ... yes
CDAP-plugins / data-generator ... yes
Lorenzo Faccioli / hubspot_migration ... yes
CDAP-plugins / java-basics ... yes
cdapio_old / cdap-build ... yes
IOSS / cdap-mirroring ... yes
cdapio_old / hydrator-plugins ... yes
cdapio_old / cdap-security-extn ... yes
cdapio_old / wrangler ... yes
cdapio_old / bigquery-delta-plugins ... yes
cdapio_old / delta ... yes
cdapio_old / database-delta-plugins ... yes
cdapio_old / amazon-s3-plugins ... yes
cdapio_old / azure ... yes
cdapio_old / condition-plugins ... yes
cdapio_old / google-cloud ... yes
cdapio_old / kafka-plugins ... yes
cdapio_old / mmds ... yes
Lorenzo Faccioli / Get refresh token ... yes
cdapio_old / cdap ... yes
cdapio_old / cdap-ui ... yes
CDAP-plugins / Get Refresh Token ... yes
CDAP-plugins / Google Drive refresh token ... yes
Lorenzo Faccioli / test ... yes
test-group / Repotest ... yes
cdapio_old / mirroring-test ... yes
cdapio / cdap-build ... yes
cdapio / cdap ... yes
cdapio / cdap-ui ... yes
cdapio / hydrator-plugins ... yes
cdapio / cdap-security-extn ... yes
cdapio / wrangler ... yes
cdapio / bigquery-delta-plugins ... yes
cdapio / delta ... yes
cdapio / database-delta-plugins ... yes
cdapio / amazon-s3-plugins ... yes
cdapio / azure ... yes
cdapio / condition-plugins ... yes
cdapio / google-cloud ... yes
cdapio / kafka-plugins ... yes
cdapio / mmds ... yes
Ossama Assaghir / mirroring-test ... yes
CDAP-plugins / elasticsearch-plugins-release-1.10 ... yes
CDAP-plugins / test_besma ... yes
CDAP-plugins / elasticsearch-plugins-release-1.10.0 ... yes
cdapio / elasticsearch-plugins ... yes
IOSS / SpecializedScraperPOC ... yes
Redis version >= 4.0.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.5.3 ? ... yes (2.7.2)
Git version >= 2.29.0 ? ... yes (2.29.0)
Git user has default SSH configuration? ... yes
Active users: ... 40
Is authorized keys file accessible? ... yes
GitLab configured to store new projects in hashed storage? ... yes
All projects are in hashed storage? ... yes

Checking GitLab App ... Finished


Checking GitLab subtasks ... Finished
```

For ldap error it's just because ldap server is shut down at the moment

here is **gitlab-reails/production.log** when i click a project

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==

```
ActionView::Template::Error ():
    128:           = render_if_exists 'layouts/nav/sidebar/project_jira_issues_link', issue_tracker: issue_tracker
    129:         - else
    130:           = nav_link do
    131:             = link_to issue_tracker.issue_tracker_path, target: '_blank', rel: 'noopener noreferrer', class: 'shortcuts-external_tracker' do
    132:               .nav-icon-container
    133:                 = sprite_icon('external-link')
    134:               %span.nav-item-name

app/models/project_services/data_fields.rb:14:in `url'
app/models/project_services/issue_tracker_service.rb:63:in `issue_tracker_path'
app/views/layouts/nav/sidebar/_project.html.haml:131
app/helpers/tab_helper.rb:78:in `nav_link'
app/views/layouts/nav/sidebar/_project.html.haml:130
app/views/layouts/_page.html.haml:3
app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:13
app/views/layouts/project.html.haml:16
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:134:in `render'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:554:in `block in allow_gitaly_ref_name_caching'
lib/gitlab/gitaly_client.rb:318:in `allow_ref_name_caching'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:553:in `allow_gitaly_ref_name_caching'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:499:in `set_current_admin'
lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in `with_session'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:490:in `set_session_storage'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:73:in `with_locale'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:79:in `with_user_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:484:in `set_locale'
lib/gitlab/error_tracking.rb:52:in `with_context'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:549:in `sentry_context'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:477:in `block in set_current_context'
lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:54:in `block in use'
lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:54:in `use'
lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:21:in `with_context'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:469:in `set_current_context'
lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
lib/gitlab/jira/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:21:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:234:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:50:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_malformed_strings.rb:21:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:23:in `call'
config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:9:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:76:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:12:in `call'
```

thank you in advance !

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem I had to migrate **`gitlab-secrets.json`** from **`/etc/gitlab`** too, because this file contains the database encryption key, CI/CD variables, and variables used for two-factor authentication.
If you fail to restore this encryption key file along with the application data backup, users with two-factor authentication enabled and GitLab Runner lose access to your GitLab server.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I still have the same problem.

Comment: is it a gitlab backup restore that u did or something else that caused the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> To restore a backup, you must restore /etc/gitlab/gitlab-secrets.json (for Omnibus packages) or /home/git/gitlab/.secret (for installations from source). This file contains the database encryption key, CI/CD variables, and variables used for two-factor authentication. If you fail to restore this encryption key file along with the application data backup, users with two-factor authentication enabled and GitLab Runner loses access to your GitLab server.